# Can't compile Maven project in WSL2 from Windows IntelliJ

Tags: windows, maven, wsl-2

I am trying to use IntelliJ with WSL2 but I'm experiencing problems. I created a dummy project with a simple main class printing hello world. I placed the project in my WSL file system. When I try to run/build with IntelliJ, I get this message:

```
Maven resources compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'testproject' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.
```

Why is this happening? I can build the project just fine using maven downloaded with `sudo apt get install maven` from a WSL2 Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is because your project is located in your windows file system. To solve it, when you create or open a project make sure that the location of this is in a wsl directory (for example -> \wsl$\Ubuntu\home\andre\IdeaProjectsInWSL\MyProject).

[image: project location]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html#crete_project_for_wsl

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, IntelliJ installed on windows has issue with opening and working with wsl files.

I have installed linux varient intellij on wsl distro itself. latest wsl supports GUI apps. Its good enough for me.